# Apex - using List Question

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a Apex class :

```
public class HellowWorld{
    public List<Contact> getContacts() {    
        List<Contact> contacts = Database.query('select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i from alphabet');
        return contacts;  
    }
}
```

Which the developer console accepts without problems/issues.

Then I try to use this in a force page :

```
<apex:page controller="HellowWorld">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock > 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! contacts}" var="ct">
        <apex:column value="{! ct.a}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>   
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

I then receive the following error on thepage preview :

> Invalid conversion from runtime type List to List

Is anyone able to assist?

Comment: can you return list contact from your apex class?

Comment: At runtime `Database.query('select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i from alphabet');` returns the List<alphabet> not List<Contact>. At compile time, the engine doesn't know exact type of the return value. That's why it saved your code, but failed when you ran the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because, you are querying on `alphabet` object and assigning it to `List<Contact>`. And as you are using dynamic SOQL, you will get run time exception which is expected.

If you want to display `alphabets` in your visualforce page, then your controller should be something like below

```
public List<alphabet> getAlphabets() {    
    List<alphabet> alphabets = Database.query('select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i from alphabet');
    return alphabets;  
}
```

Instead of using the dynamic SOQL, you can simply use as below

```
public List<alphabet> getAlphabets() {    
    return [select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i from alphabet];
}
```

And your visualforce page should be

```
<apex:page controller="HellowWorld">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock > 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!alphabets}" var="ct">
        <apex:column value="{! ct.a}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>   
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you Vijay that worked as a charm.